# ObjectAnimator in android

Tags: android, objectanimator

I want to show a objectanimator in android for a imageview.This imageview should move from top of the screen to about 30 pixels down from top of the screen.Once it(imageview) reaches there and onclick of the imageview the image view should disappear.I have read that i cannot use translate animation as the onclick event wont get fired and hence i will have to use Objectanimator.
Can somebody please help me out in this ...stuck up for a long time now.
Following is my code i have used however it does not seem to work also i do not understand what parameters(for that points) i need to pass.

```
        ObjectAnimator scaleXOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tv, "translationX", 1f, 9f);
        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.play(scaleXIn);
        set.setDuration(1000);
        set.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use translateAnimation and add an animationlistener so when animation ends its onAnimationEnd() method will fired up, so inside it you can put the codes that was in onclick method, or you can put an if statement inside your onclicked method to check whether animation ends, for more about animations you can check out these resources

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxLa2tjhVPOZ9KMqanm12_xPDBjKPZWgM

and
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html